# Are fixed tabs swype available using support library on Android 2.3.3?

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-support-library

I'm creating a new project and I want to use 2.3.3. I'd like to have fixed tabs + swype but the project wizard says that they are available since android 3.0
are them in the support library? can't find anything about it.

I don't want to use actionbarsherlock.

I'm trying to use android.support.v7 (adding it as external jar) but it doesn't find getActionBar() method in my activity, what should I do?

Comment: Take a lookg at this video for getting started with ActionBarCompat http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TGgYqfJnyc .

You may also need to generate your own theme http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my project I solved this with a ViewPager to handle the swipes, and by using the [ViewPagerIndicator library](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) to show the "tabs". After some tweaking with the appearance -- tutorial also found on the site --, It works perfectly on GB.

Comment: the problem is that it doesn't find fragments transactions and action bar, they doesn't seem to be in the support library v4

Comment: It's possible to use a ViewPager without fragments, just add a PagerAdapter and tabs with .addTab(). Be sure to use the ViewPager in the v4 support library. You don't need to use fragments or the action bar at all.